# Question about generics and traits in Rust

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have the `DoSomethingProvider` trait that expects a parameter of one of its functions to be of trait type `DoSomethingListener`.

I have a concrete struct `DoSomethingManager` that has a member of type `DoSomethingProvider`, and will implement the `DoSomethingListener` trait and pass it self as a listener to `DoSomethingProvider`.

Hopefully the code will illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
pub trait DoSomethingListener {
    fn something_was_done(msg: &str);
}

pub trait DoSomethingProvider<'a, T>
where
    T: DoSomethingListener,
{
    fn add_do_something_listener(listener: T);
}

/* note:  The struct below will implement DoSomethingListener, and has
 * a DoSomethingProvider field.  It will pass itself as a listener to
 * DoSomethingProvider (which listens to a message queue and notifies
 * listeners of certain events)
 */

//this doesn't work.  Compiler complains about unused type T
pub struct DoSomethingManager<'a, B, T>
where
    T: DoSomethingListener,
    B: DoSomethingProvider<'a, T>,
{
    provider: Box<B>,
    // doesn't have any member of type T
}

// ...

/* So I tried this:
 * this doesn't work.  Compiler complains that DoSomethingProvider
 * expects one type parameter
 */
pub struct DoSomethingManager<'a, B>
where
    B: DoSomethingProvider<'a>,
{
    provider: Box<B>,
    // doesn't have any member of type T
}

//...

/* this compiles, but its a hack */
pub struct DoSomethingManager<'a, B, T>
where
    T: DoSomethingListener,
    B: DoSomethingProvider<'a, T>,
{
    provider: Box<B>,
    dummy: Box<T>,
    // added unused dummy member of type T
}
```

I am an experienced Python developer but I'm new to Rust. What is the proper way to implement this polymorphic code in Rust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `DoSomethingProvider` to use an [associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#specifying-placeholder-types-in-trait-definitions-with-associated-types) instead of a type parameter for the listener type.

```
pub trait DoSomethingListener {
    fn something_was_done(msg: &str);
}

pub trait DoSomethingProvider {
    type Listener: DoSomethingListener;

    fn add_do_something_listener(listener: Self::Listener);
}

pub struct DoSomethingManager<B>
where
    B: DoSomethingProvider,
{
    provider: Box<B>,
}
```

Note that by using either an associated type or a type parameter, a particular instance of `DoSomethingProvider` will only be able to accept listeners of a single specific type. If you want to be able to register listeners of various types, you will need to use dynamic dispatch via [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html).

Comment: Thanks.  Trait objects provide the behavior I was after.  Now I have to wrap my head around when to use associated types, type parameters, or trait objects...

Answer (score 0):

What I got to compile is not far off of what has to be done to resolve this, but I don't like the solution. It seems you *do* have to add a dummy field that uses the type with [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html).